# Derivative of a Euclidean distance matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let's say I have $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, a collection of $n$ row vectors of size $d$. We can calculate an $n \times n$ distance matrix, $D$, from $X$, where each $\{i,j\}$ entry denotes the squared L2 distance between the vectors $X_i$ and $X_j$. That is,

$$
D_{ij} = \|X_{i} - X_{j}\|_2^2 = \sum_{d}(X_{id} - X_{jd})^2
$$

I wish to find the derivative of D with respect to X. Since this is a matrix by matrix operation, I'm aware that this would probably resolve to a fourth-order tensor. This is what I tried so far ($\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta):

$$
\frac{\partial D_{ij}}{\partial X_{kl}} = \frac{\sum_{d}(X_{id} - X_{jd})^2}{\partial X_{kl}} = 2\sum_{d}(X_{id} - X_{jd}) \left ( \frac{\partial X_{id}}{\partial X_{kl}} - \frac{\partial X_{jd}}{\partial X_{kl}} \right )
$$

$$
= 2\sum_{d}(X_{id} - X_{jd})(\delta_{ik}\delta_{dl} - \delta_{jk}\delta_{dl}) \\
= 2\sum_{d}(X_{id} - X_{jd})(\delta_{ik} - \delta_{jk}) \delta_{dl} \\
= 2\sum_{d}(X_{id}\delta_{ik} - X_{jd}\delta_{ik} - X_{id}\delta_{jk} + X_{jd}\delta_{jk})\delta_{dl}\\
= 2\sum_{d}(X_{kd} - X_{jd}\delta_{ik} - X_{id}\delta_{jk} + X_{kd})\delta_{dl}\\
= 2(2X_{kd}\delta_{dl} - X_{jd}\delta_{ik}\delta_{dl} - X_{id}\delta_{jk}\delta_{dl})\\
= 4X_{kl} - 2(X_{jl}\delta_{ik} + X_{il}\delta_{jk})
$$

I'm not entirely sure that what I've derived is correct. The sum between $X_{kl}$ and the fourth order terms seem strange, and the fourth order terms are also hard to interpret; I think the fourth order terms can be interpreted like this; if $Y_{ijkl} = X_{jl}\delta_{ik}$:
$$
Y_{ijkl} = 
\begin{cases}
      X_{jl}, & \text{if}\ i=k \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
$$

It would be great if someone could point me to some way to get this derivative (or perhaps some other vectorized solution).

Comment: Using tensor calculus I get ${\left(\frac{\partial D}{\partial X}\right)^{i'}}_{ijd'}
=2 ({X^d}_i - {X^d}_j) 1_d \delta^d_{d'} (\delta^{i'}_i - \delta^{i'}_j)
$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\d{\delta} \def\e{\bar{e}}
\def\h{\odot}  \def\w{\widehat}   \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\E{\w{E}}  \def\Eij{\E_{ij}}
\def\Ekl{\E_{kl}}
\def\Elk{\E_{lk}}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The distance matrix can be written using the Hadamard product $(\h)$
and the all-ones matrix $J$ (with the same dimensions as $X)$
$$\eqalign{
D = (X\h X)^TJ + J^T(X\h X) - 2X^TX \\
}$$
The component-wise self-gradient of a matrix  is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{X}{X_{kl}} &= \e_k\e_l^T \;=\; \Ekl \\
\grad{X^T}{X_{kl}} &= \gradLR{X}{X_{kl}}^T \,=\; \Elk \\
}$$
where $\e_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ Cartesian basis vector and $\E_{kl}$ is the matrix whose components are all zero, except for the $(k,l)$ component which equals one.

The gradients wrt the components of $X$ can then be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
\grad{D}{X_{kl}}
 &= 2(X\h\Ekl)^TJ + 2J^T(X\h\Ekl) - 2\Elk X - 2X^T\Ekl \\
}$$

---

Extracting the individual components of this expression gets uglier.

First note the following equalities $({\rm where}\ \o$ is the all-ones vector)
$$\eqalign{
\Eij\,\e_k &= \e_i\e_j^T\e_k \:=\: \e_i\,\d_{jk} \\
\e_k^T\Eij &= \e_k^T\e_i\e_j^T \:=\: \d_{ki}\,\e_j^T \\
J\e_k &= \o, \qquad \e_k^TJ = \o^T \\
(A\h B)\,\e_k &= A\e_k\h B \e_k \\
\e_k^T(A\h B) &= \e_k^TA\h \e_k^TB \\
}$$

Now extract the components of the previously derived expression
$$\eqalign{
\grad{D_{ij}}{X_{kl}} &= \e_i^T\gradLR{D}{X_{kl}}\e_j \\
 &= 2(\e_i^TX\h\e_i^T\Ekl)^T\o + 2\o^T(X\e_j\h\Ekl\e_j)
  - 2\d_{il}(\e_k^TX\e_j) - 2(\e_i^TX^T\e_k)\d_{lj} \\
 &= 2\d_{ik}(\e_i^TX\h\e_l^T)^T\o + 2\d_{lj}\o^T(X\e_j\h\e_k)
  - 2\d_{il}X_{kj} - 2\d_{lj}X_{ki} \\
 &= 2\d_{ik}X_{il} + 2\d_{lj}X_{kj}
  - 2\d_{il}X_{kj} - 2\d_{lj}X_{ki} \\
}$$
Depending on your mathematical background, you may be *tempted* to apply the Einstein summation convention and sum over the repeated indices in the first two terms.

To avoid this temptation, let's introduce the third-order tensor
$$
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\H_{ijk} = \begin{cases}
\o\qquad{\rm if}\;\;i=j=k \\
 0\qquad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$
and rewrite the result in a form consistent with the summation convention and also balance the indices on the RHS by including
explicit factors of unity (i.e. components of the $\o$ vector)
$$\eqalign{
\grad{D_{ij}}{X_{kl}}
 &= 2\d_{pk}\H_{piq}X_{ql}\o_{j} + 2\d_{lp}\H_{pjq}X_{kq}\o_{i}
  - 2\d_{il}X_{kj} - 2\d_{lj}X_{ki} \\
 &= 2\,\H_{ikq}X_{ql}\o_{j} + 2X_{kq}\H_{qlj}\o_{i}
  - 2\d_{il}X_{kj} - 2\d_{lj}X_{ki} \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Mercury Re-reading your question, you want the distance between rows of $X$, whereas my derivation is for the distance between the columns of $X$. So you'll need to replace every $X$ in my post with $X^T.\;$ Sorry about that, my default mental mode is geared toward column vectors.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, it's still quite helpful. I'm re-deriving it starting from $(X \odot X)J^T + J(X \odot X)^T - 2 X X^T$.